# How do I call a POST method to a RESTful service in Sencha?

Tags: rest, post, sencha-touch, extjs

ANSWER: The problem is that I am trying to make a cross-domain call using Ext.Ajax.Request().

I'm designing an app that will be making http POST and GET requests to a RESTful service. The service is already in place and if I use a utility like soapUI or the Chrome Rest Client to make the calls they are successful. Someone might ask: "Is this a cross domain call?" My answer: I don't know. I can tell you that the service is not hosted on my own computer but again, if I use soapUI or the Chrome Rest Client plugin for my Chrome browser I can successfully make the calls.

However, If I try to do them using Ext.Ajax.Request() they fail, almost immediately.

If I use Ext.util.JSONP.request() it won't let me do a POST. What is the solution?

Comment: Cross-domain problems only apply to JavaScript.  Any other program (such as SOAPUI) can happily make requests of any kind to any domain, as there is no such restriction in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it is impossible to use Ext.Ajax.Request() to make a call to a service not on the local machine/device. This is called cross-site/cross-domain scripting and is blocked by all browsers by default. It is possible to disable this security feature, but ONLY use that for development purposes.

If you are developing for a mobile device, I recommend developing with disabled browser security on your computer, and then using PhoneGap to package your app. PhoneGap allows cross-domain/cross-site scripting and so Ext.Ajax.Request() to an outside service will work using PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the request method in the Ajax call:

```
new Ext.Ajax.request({ url:'http://foo', method:'POST', ... });
```

See also: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

Hope this helps.

Comment: I currently am specifying that the method is a POST; I am only having that problem when I try to use Ext.util.JSONP.request(). The Ajax call fails immediately which makes me think that it cannot access the URL.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the request details with Firebug or something similar (like the Chrome dev tools)?

Comment: Where in the Chrome dev tools would I go to inspect the request? In the Javascript console under 'Network' the request details are as follows: Method: OPTIONS (I dont know why), Status: (canceled), Type: undefined

Comment: Firebug is a bit better, but in Chrome its under the Network tab; you can look at the headers, response, etc.

Comment: OPTIONS is a valid request method, but it seems odd in this context. Cancelled sounds like an error on the client side stopped the request before being fully sent. You might add handlers to the ajax call for errors and failures and write them out to the console (or alert)... maybe there is some odd error that you are not being shown.

Comment: There are only two headers defined, Access-Control-Request-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With Access-Control-Request-Method:POST. The origin is defined as localhost. All of the other tabs, including response, are empty.